# Text hovering photo is not scaling, what to do?

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

I want to excuse for not flagging last post... I did not consider it... I hope this one does not need it ;)

I still got the same problem...

> I had a certain problem. I have built a simple gallery, where images size is depend on the device resolution and hover effect shows detail information about the hovered photo. Images are scaling perfectly, but I had a problem with texts covering photos, which are not.
>
> To change it, I used @media, but after that hover text is scaling only for established resolutions. My question is what to do, to have a text scaling down like a photo, when user change window browser size to custom?

```
<section id="gallery">
        <ul class="large-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-2 small-block-grid-1">
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_08.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_02.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_03.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_04.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_05.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_06.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_07.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_08.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_09.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_10.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_11.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay"></div> <a href="#"></a> 
                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/files/img_12.jpg" alt="Ocean" />
                <div class="gallery-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                             <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#" title="title">two grils and one cup drinking togheter</a></h1>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-heart3" data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="own-tip tip-bottom" title="Dislike video"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">422</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">likes</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <div class="small-4 columns text-center">
                                <img src="http://fkdesign.pl/zurb/img/sep.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <dl class="small-4 columns text-center"> <dt><span class="icon-eye3"></span></dt>

                                <dd><span class="value">323</span>

                                </dd>
                                <dd><span class="name">views</span>

                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

[Here is link to jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/draszka/Set6b/14/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the direction and solution to your problem:

I bet you want to do something similar to [Paravel's FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)
It is a jQuery plugin. You need to run [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to run it.

Instead of a complete code example, I leave the solution direction and space for you to explore first which can help you to learn in long run.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try to use your hint and later public results. Is it the only solution?

Comment: Glad that I can inspire and help you. There are lots of solutions nowadays. Many people have invented good stuff, another plugin is [simplefocus's FlowType.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/). I think a right keywords can help you to search, I used "fit font size responsive" in this case.

Comment: I was trying to use flowtype.js, but i got some problem... when I set script for headers using min and max font size properties to scale text, script has used his own default sizes and scaled improperly. When I seted script for whole text inside #gallery it's even not working. Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/draszka/Set6b/21/

Comment: It's not working also for body... there should be problem with my CSS I think, could you steer me where is the point?

Comment: I have tried your demo, it seems that you haven't load the flowtext plugin. You have to download from github and load it into your web page after jQuery UI. eg. <script src="js/flowtype.js"></script> which your parameter is working

Comment: It was loaded as external file, now for better view I have added it to fiddles code frame.
http://jsfiddle.net/draszka/P8scC/1/

Comment: The example is hard to test in jsfiddle, since there is a left bar and text is hidden by default. I have clone your page and created a demo at [responsive-text-flow](http://zenrity.com/demo/responsive-text-flow/) I have removed the left side bar and hide display by default. See if it is the effect you expected? (BTW, I recommend to use maximum and minimum to control since you are doing the text flow depending on image size, and fontRatio 30 is a good start from website example)

Comment: Great! It works with headers also for me. Thank you very much! But... what with the rest of hovering text? Seting size for .gallery-info container with flowtype doesn't work... I was trying also set script for every text element inside this container but it only change the line-height for those.

Comment: Okey! This time I have used FitText.js, set elements which should be scaled and finally it works as I wanted :) Thank you very much for you help! Problem with scaling other elements - that I mentioned in last comment  was caused displaying them as in-line elements not block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a viewport metatag in the head?
Have you tried using percents instead of rem?
A standard font-size base for the body tag may help too.

Comment: yes i got viewport metatag. I did, percents and rems (set as default) are not working.